# C# Producer/Consumer pattern

Tags: c#, producer-consumer

I have simple one-producer/two-consumers code as follows but the output shows that only `C2` is consuming. Are there any bugs in my code?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Object lockObj = new object();
        Queue<string>  queue = new Queue<string>();
        Producer p = new Producer(queue, lockObj);
        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(queue, lockObj, "c1");
        Consumer c2 = new Consumer(queue, lockObj, "c2");

        Thread t1 = new Thread(c1.consume);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(c2.consume);
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        Thread t = new Thread(p.produce);
        t.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    } 
}
public class Producer
{
    Queue<string> queue;
    Object lockObject;
    static int seq = 0;
    public Producer(Queue<string> queue, Object lockObject)
    {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.lockObject = lockObject; 
    }

    public void produce()
    {
        while( seq++ <15) //just testinng 15 items
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                string item = "item" + seq;
                queue.Enqueue(item);
                Console.WriteLine("Producing {0}", item);
                if (queue.Count == 1)
                { // first
                    Monitor.PulseAll(lockObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Consumer
{
    Queue<string> queue;
    Object lockObject;
    string name;
    public Consumer(Queue<string> queue, Object lockObject, string name)
    {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.lockObject = lockObject; 
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void consume()
    {
        string item;
        while (true)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (queue.Count == 0)
                { 
                    Monitor.Wait(lockObject);
                    continue; 
                }
                item = queue.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine(" {0} Consuming {1}", name, item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Producing item1
 c2 Consuming item1

Producing item2
 c2 Consuming item2

Producing item3
 c2 Consuming item3

Producing item4
 c2 Consuming item4

Producing item5
 c2 Consuming item5

Producing item6
 c2 Consuming item6

Producing item7
 c2 Consuming item7

Producing item8
 c2 Consuming item8

Producing item9
 c2 Consuming item9

Producing item10
 c2 Consuming item10

Producing item11
 c2 Consuming item11

Producing item12
 c2 Consuming item12

Producing item13
 c2 Consuming item13

Producing item14
 c2 Consuming item14

Producing item15
 c2 Consuming item15
```

Comment: Could you describe what exactly you are trying to achieve? Your example looks a bit contrived, so I can't determine from context what you need to do.

Comment: Hi Southsouth, please take a look at [this Producer-Consumer example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733793/implementing-the-producer-consumer-pattern-in-c-sharp/47179576#47179576), it may help you.

Answer (score 6):

First, I can't reproduce your problem, here both threads consume some of the items. I guess your machine is faster but adding Sleep like gw suggest will solve that. 
What I would also suggest is that you don't try to sync the producer, I mean let it queue items as fast as it can and let the consumers sync to see who handles each item.
I made a quick modification and it seems to be working fine:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Object lockObj = new object();
        Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
        Producer p = new Producer(queue);
        Comsumer c1 = new Comsumer(queue, lockObj, "c1");
        Comsumer c2 = new Comsumer(queue, lockObj, "c2");

        Thread t1 = new Thread(c1.consume);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(c2.consume);
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        Thread t = new Thread(p.produce);
        t.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class Producer
{
    Queue<string> queue;
    static int seq;
    public Producer(Queue<string> queue)
    {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void produce()
    {
        while (seq++ < 1000) //just testinng 15 items
        {
            string item = "item" + seq;
            queue.Enqueue(item);
            Console.WriteLine("Producing {0}", item);                
        }
    }
}

public class Comsumer
{
    Queue<string> queue;
    Object lockObject;
    string name;
    public Comsumer(Queue<string> queue, Object lockObject, string name)
    {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.lockObject = lockObject;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void consume()
    {
        string item;
        while (true)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (queue.Count == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                item = queue.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine(" {0} Comsuming {1}", name, item);
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

You may also add the sleep to slow down the consumer loops.

Comment: No, I actually tested the original code and got some outputs from c1 and some from c2.

Answer (score 4):

For testing purposes, try adding a time delay inside the consumer code.  It may be the case that "consumption" is so fast that one consumer thread empties the queue before the other consumer thread has a chance.

(edit)

As I suspected, adding a

Thread.Sleep(500);

inside the consumer thread (to simulate some lengthy processing going on) results in both threads being utilized.

Answer (score 2):

Your producer only calls Monitor.PulseAll when the queue count is equal to 1 which will not be very often as nothing of substance is being done by the producer, this means that the first consume thread through the gate gets to dequeue the first item, the second consume thread will see no items in the queue and so hit the Monitor.Wait, and the Pulse won't happen again (probably until all but the last item is left) so that second thread will sit in that wait infinitely.

Comment: When the first consume thread through the gate gets to dequeue, the queue.Count becomes 0 and the next time the producer enqueue an item, the PulseAll will be hit again. I cannot see why the second thread will sit and wait infinitely in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Added Thread.Sleep(500); in Consumer.comsume

then I have the following,

c2 Comsuming item1
c1 Comsuming item2
c2 Comsuming item3
c1 Comsuming item4
c2 Comsuming item5
c1 Comsuming item6
c2 Comsuming item7
c1 Comsuming item8
.....
the resule is not uncertain after adding Sleep.

Comment: Which consumer consumes which item is uncertain and I think it wouldn't conflict with author's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I ran you code and had spurts of c1 doing the consuming and spurts of c2. You may just want to check this link from msdn: [How to: Synchronize a Producer and a Consumer Thread (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: The article has actually bugs in its suggested implementation. Scroll to the comments section in the linked article to see them.

Answer (score 0):

I think your purpose is to have more than one consume threads working "in parallel". But your code is low efficient. The two consume threads are working sequentially essentially. The actual working code should be put outside the lock so the two consumer threads can run in real parallel. This improves runtime if you have multiple cores or even on a single core machine depending on the property of the work. Otherwise, there is actually no point to have more than one consume thread because anyway, all consume threads run in sequential.

Comment: Thanks Steve, do you have an example?