# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'rchsdtOut' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#

So I am getting this cross thread error and I cannot figure it out.  Here is my base code before I attempted to muck around with it.

Bascally what the code is going is calling a batch file which then calls a java file.  The outputdata is then redirected to the console in real time.  When I just redirect the output just to the C# console, it works fine.  But I want the same info to print out into a rich text box within the app.  VS 2010 complaines at rchsdtOut.Text = e.Data.ToString();
that Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'rchsdtOut' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I have tried looking this up, and I do admit I am new to threading, so any help on how to easy accomplish this would be appreciated.

```
   //Declare and instantiate a new process component.
    System.Diagnostics.Process process1;
    process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "BATFile.bat";
    process1.OutputDataReceived += (s, a) => myMethod(a);
    process1.Start();
    process1.BeginOutputReadLine(); 
    process1.WaitForExit();
    process1.Close(); 


    private void myMethod(DataReceivedEventArgs e) {       
       if (e.Data != null)
        {         
           rchsdtOut.Text = e.Data.ToString();
           Console.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());

        } 
    }//end of private
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not legal to access a WinForms control from a thread other than the one it was created on.  You need to use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to get control back to the appropriate thread.

```
private void myMethod(DataReceivedEventArgs e) {       
  if (e.Data != null) {
    Action action = () => rchstdOut.Text = e.Data.ToString();
    rchstdOut.Invoke(action, null);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is a better solution than mine, because it waits to marshal until it is sure that the payload isn't null.

Comment: @user1158745 that's really odd. Try using BeginInvoke instead of Invoke

Comment: Well the app doesn't appear to hang, but nothing is logged.

Comment: @user1158745 that likely means you aren't pumping your UI thread to let messages through.  The problem appears to be the call to `WaitForExit`.  That will block the UI thread and messages until the app completes.  Try removing that call and it should start working as expected

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Only issue, it doesn't seem to be appending to the richtextbox, but just overwriting it.  anyideas?

Comment: This seemed to do is   Action action = () => rchsdtOut.Text += "\r\n" + e.Data.ToString();  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Try this line:

```
process1.OutputDataReceived += (s, a) => rchsdtOut.Invoke(new System.Action(()=> myMethod(a)));
```

Comment: I added that line, but vs2010 indicates that cannot convert lambda expression type 'system.delegate' becuase it's not a delegate type.

Answer (score 0):

Well `rchsdtOut` can only be upodated from the UI thread while your method is called from another.
There are several solutions. If you want to have a general method to update controls you can check the control.[InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property (or this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() in WPF) and use a delegate.

```
    private delegate void UpdateTextControlDelegate(Control control, string text);

    private void UpdateTextControl(Control control, string text)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new UpdateTextControlDelegate(UpdateTextControl), new object[] { control, text});
            return;
        }

        control.Text = text;
    }
```

...

```
if (e.Data != null)
{         
     UpdateTextControl(rchsdtOut, e.Data.ToString());
     Console.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());
}
```

Comment: No need for checking here- the OP is explicitly starting a thread, so we *know* an Invoke is needed.

Comment: True, however this way you can reuse the function in case you need it to be called not JUST by the OutputDataReceived event.

Comment: I wanted to give this method a try, howerver, vs2010 doesn't like the 2nd new[].  Indicates no best type found for implicitly-typed array.

Comment: You can just use 'new object[]'.

Comment: I gave that a try, but nothing is being written to the richtext box.

Comment: What is the value of `e.Data`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a Form Control from a thread other then where it was created.
You will need to create some other object that both of the threads can access.
[Producer Consumer Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371249/c-sharp-producer-consumer-pattern)