# How to post results of Parallel.ForEach to a queue which is continually read in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

In my application I have three classes, `Extractor`, `Transformer` and `Loader`, which are coordinated by a fourth class, `Coordinator`. `Extractor`, `Transformer` and `Loader` are very simple and do the following:

**`Extractor`**

Exposes a member called `Results` of type `IEnumerable<string>`, for example by reading from a text file. Extraction should be synchronous.

**`Transformer`**

Exposes a member called `Transform` which accepts a string and transforms it to another string via some process which is expected to be time-consuming (use parallel processing here).

**`Loader`**

Exposes a member called `Load` which accepts a string and loads it into some final form (e.g. another text file). Loading should be synchronous.

The `Coordinator` classes coordinates the three operations. The transformation process should be done in parallel, and then push the results to a queue which is read by the loader. `Coordinator`'s `Run()` method looks like this:

```
Extractor extractor = new Extractor();
Transformer transformer = new Transformer();
Loader loader = new Loader();

ConcurrentQueue<string> outputs = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

Parallel.ForEach(extractor.Results, x => outputs.Enqueue(transformer.Transform(x)));

foreach(string output in outputs)
{
  loader.Load(output);
}
```

This is working well, except that ALL transformation must be finished before any loading can be done - i.e. the `Parallel.ForEach()` completes before the following `foreach` starts. I would prefer that each output is passed to the loader as soon as it is ready.

I also tried this:

```
Extractor extractor = new Extractor();
Transformer transformer = new Transformer();
Loader loader = new Loader();

ConcurrentQueue<string> outputs = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

foreach (string input in extractor.Results)
{
  string input1 = input;
  Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () => outputs.Enqueue(transformer.Transform(input1)));
}

foreach(string output in outputs)
{
  loader.Load(output);
}
```

But then the `foreach` loop at the bottom gets hit before any outputs have been added to the queue, and so it simply exits.

How do I get loading to happen as soon as results are available from the calls to `transformer.Transform()`?

Comment: Look into the Producer/Consumer pattern. Old now, but here's a c# simple example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656404/c-sharp-producer-consumer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) instead with [`Parallel.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke.aspx).  In the example below, [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) (the *Consumer* part of the Producer-Consumer pattern) won't finish until [`CompleteAdding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) is called so `load` will run until `fill` is completed.

```
var outputs = new BlockingCollection<string>();

// aka Producer
Action fill = () => {
    Parallel.ForEach(extractor.Results, x => outputs.Add(transformer.Transform(x)));        
    outputs.CompleteAdding();
};

// aka Consumer
Action load = () => {
   foreach(var o in outputs.GetConsumingEnumerable()) 
       loader.Load(o);
}

Parallel.Invoke(fill, load);
```

Comment: This is a whole bunch of stuff which is new to me. Thanks!

Comment: This hit the proverbial nail right on its proverbial head. I love you (proverbially).