# Perform multiple tasks async in parallel and save results to database UnitOfWork is null

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, async-await

I recently posted another question about how to process a list of items from a database and retry 3 times if the process fails.

The question can be found here: [C# process large list of items in a loop and retry if fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519419/c-sharp-process-large-list-of-items-in-a-loop-and-retry-if-fails/25521924#25521924)

I made some changes to the answer I received to that question and here is the code:

I have an abstract class which inherits `ApiController` class and all my Web Api controllers inherit the `ApiBaseController`:

In the `ApiBaseController` I have defined the UnitOfWork that uses Repository pattern in order to CRUD the SQL db. The UnitOfWork and repository pattern works fine, I have tested it and I have no problems with it.

```
public abstract class ApiBaseController : ApiController
{
    protected UnitOfWork Uow { get; set; }          

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (Uow != null && Uow is IDisposable)
        {
            ((IDisposable)Uow).Dispose();
            Uow = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Here I have a `JobController` which inherits the `ApiBaseController` which inherits the `ApiController` that makes it a Web Api Controller.

This controller has one endpoint `api/endpoint/sendrequests` which when is called will get all the `Jobs` from the db and process them in batches of 10.

The method `ProcessTaskAsync` will process every individual task retrieved from database and if it fails then it will try to process it 2 more times until the task will be ignored.

Everything works fine and nice except that in the `ProcessTaskAsync` after the task is processed I try to save the result of the task to the database using the UnitOfWork `await Uow.Results.AddAsync(result);`. Here it fails! The problem is the `Uow` object is null and I don't get it why. I am thinking is because the tasks are processed asynchronously the controller execution ends that means the controller is disposed and so the UnitOfWork.

Any idea why the `Uow` is null and how can I solve this?

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[RoutePrefix("api/endpoint")]
public class JobController : ApiBaseController
{

private const int PAGED_LIST_SIZE = 10;

private const int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 3;

public JobController()
{
    Uow = new UnitOfWork();          
}       

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("sendrequests")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendRequests()
{
    try
    {              

        var items = await Uow.Jobs.GetAllAsync();

        await ProcessTasks(items);                

        return Ok();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}


private async Task ProcessTasks(List<Job> items)
{
    var pagedResults = items.Paged<Job>(PAGED_LIST_SIZE);

    if (pagedResults != null && pagedResults.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var collection in pagedResults)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

            foreach (var item in collection.ToList())
            {
                var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessTaskAsync(item));
                tasks.Add(task);
            }

            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());                   
            }
            catch (Exception ez)
            {
                //log here the failed ones
            }
        }
    }

}

private async void ProcessTaskAsync(Job item)
{
    if (item.Processed >= MAX_RETRY_COUNT)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Max count {0} reached for task: {1} ", item.Processed.ToString(), item.Name));
        return;
    }

    item.Processed++;

    try
    {
        Result result = await item.Process();

        if (result != null)
        {
           await Uow.Results.AddAsync(result);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("working item name: {0}", item.Name));
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception occured: {0}", ex.Message.ToString()));            
        ProcessTaskAsync(item);
    }
}
```

This is used in order to return a List as List paged by 10. This is located into a static class.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Paged<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int chunkSize = 10)
{
    int itemsReturned = 0;
    var list = enumerable.ToList();
    while (itemsReturned < list.Count)
    {
        int currentChunkSize = Math.Min(chunkSize, list.Count - itemsReturned);
        yield return list.GetRange(itemsReturned, currentChunkSize);
        itemsReturned += currentChunkSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private async void ProcessTaskAsync(Job item)
```

The actual work method has to return `Task` that you can await on. `async void` is good probably only for things like top-level UI events, definitely not awaitable work.

You spawn work like this with `Task.Factory.StartNew` and await the results. But what you're awaiting is only the outer task (and there's no inner task, it's `void`) which starts the work. I think you're right that your Controller gets disposed before the worker methods get to use your `UoW` instance - because you're not actually awaiting that work in the Controller method.

What you should do is get rid of the `Task.Factory.StartNew` (which is used for parallel work, not asynchronous), and make the `ProcessTaskAsync` return a `Task` signalling when the actual work is done. Then you can await those `Task`s with the `WhenAll` instead, and it should work as intended.

---

Possibly the best reference/resource for `async`-related stuff is Stephen Cleary's blog. I highly recommend reading through the TPL articles http://blog.stephencleary.com/