# Bind a WPF control to a ObeservableCollection modified by a background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This is a continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131305/threading-serial-port-query-and-using-the-result-in-a-listview-control)
Here's my mainwindow.cs

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<string> store;
    public MainWindow()
    {
     SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort(SerialCom.findCOMPort(), 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
     _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
     string[] query = new string[3] { "t02", "t03", "t04" };
     store = new ObservableCollection<string> { " ", " ", " " };
     this.DataContext = this;
     Thread thread = new Thread(delegate(){Process(store,query,_serialPort);});
     thread.IsBackground = true;
     try
     {
        thread.Start(); //catch sudden serial port closure exception
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        thread.Abort();
     }
   }

 public static void Process(ObservableCollection<string> store, string[] query, SerialPort _serialPort)
 {          
     while (true)
     {             
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         {
             string add = SerialCom.returnData(query[i], _serialPort);
             if (store[i] != add)
             {
                 store.Insert(i,add);
             }
         }             
         Thread.Sleep(300);

     }
 }
```

I have a WPF listview control in my XAML page. I would like to bind that control to the ObservableCollection being changed in the non UI thread. It seems like the fly in the ointment is the infinite loop I have to query the device while the program is running.In addition, since ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged, when I bind the collection to the control, the control should automatically update without any other code in code behind or XAML?

Comment: When you bind the observablecollection to the listview, it is owned by the UI thread. If you want to update the collection, I think you need to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and all should be well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good solution in 4.5 using the `BindingOperations` class:
http://10rem.net/blog/2012/01/16/wpf-45-observable-collection-cross-thread-change-notification

For earlier versions, you'll either need to update the collection on the dispatcher thread, or push the change notification events to the dispatcher thread:
http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=41

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thankfully I can distribute with net 4.5!

Comment: Ok, I tried making my list view's ItemSource "store" via codebehind but it throws "TargetInvocationException", InnerException being "NullReferenceException" Here's my new code `store = new ObservableCollection<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(store, _lock); //allows for cross thread binding 
            Thread thread = new Thread(delegate(){Process(store,query,_serialPort);});
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            listview1.ItemsSource = store;`

Comment: The code doesn't come out too well in the comments. The most obvious thing to check would be that you've set the `_lock` object before calling the `EnableCollectionSynchronization` method..

Comment: What's strange is that I get the exact same exception if I comment out the BindingOperations call._lock is newed before I call the method. I made sure that the ObservableCollection has some values before I set it to be the ItemsSource. Would the problems listed in [this](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/01/20/wpf-45-cross-thread-collection-synchronization-redux) be relevant?

Comment: Sounds like it could be, particularly the need to lock your own access to the collection. Try adding a `lock(_lock){...}` block around the `if (store[i] != add) { store.Insert(i, add); }` block.

Comment: I found that putting the ItemSource call in a WindowLoaded event solved this. I found while debugging that MainWindow would get to the ItemSource call before drawing the windows(which is a bit obvious but still!).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the ObservableCollection from the binding system, you are not allowed to update it from a background thread.  This is because the update notifications (via INotifyCollectionChanged) occur on the thread that makes the changes.  Changes to the ObservableCollection must be dispatched to the UI thread.